# HPCC Systems - Can't change default port for Dali

Tags: ubuntu, installation, port, dali, hpcc

I'm installing HPCC Systems in ubuntu 20.04
When starting the application it fails because Dali, tries to use port 7070 which is alredy in use by another application.
I changed the port in the environment.xml file, and restarted HPCC but it continues trying to connect to 7070 as if ignoring the environment file.

The error in the logs: (after changing the port to something else)

```
0000000F USR 2021-11-24 13:07:03.776 3866411 3866411 "DASERVER[0] starting - listening to port 7070"
00000010 OPR 2021-11-24 13:07:03.778 3866411 3866411 "ERROR: -7: daserver.cpp(817) : Exception : port in use
```

Does anybody know how to change this default port?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a recent fix for this.  As of this writing, the fix has not been published in a released version of the HPCC Systems platform but it will likely be available soon (i.e. in version 8.4.16).

See https://track.hpccsystems.com/browse/HPCC-26880